# Is there a way to force app relaunch after it was killed by the Android OS?

Tags: android

Simple put: I want the app to relaunch (yes, from the launch activity, like if the user just tapped the icon button) every time Android kills my task because of lacking resources reasons.

The reason is that instead of managing everything that could possible go wrong after the app came back "from the dead", like NPEs, I want to start all over from the beginning.

I've searched for a "good practice" solution, but nothing came across.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I don't want to *force* the app back to foreground. However, *if* the user do it, I mean he brings it back to fore by his own free will, *if* Android killed my app because of resources purposes, I want the app to relaunch.

Sorry for not being clear previously.

Comment: Is that what the *user* wants?

Comment: Yes, doing it won't harm the app, it has a really small activites tree.

Comment: @lelloman: I have no idea why you think that is a "good practice". **Only have a service running when it is actively delivering value to the user**. Do not try to hack Android's memory management just to keep your process around because you do not want to take the time to write decent code.

Comment: You want the app to open like the user has clicked on its icon? Or you just want it to silently start over without popping up?

Comment: @JulioE.RodríguezCabañas clicked on icon

Comment: That won't happen in Android Q, thank the lord

Comment: What you want is currently discouraged and will actually be impossible in android Q. Please see my answer for more info.

Comment: It think I wasn't clear, did some edit on the question

Answer (score 1):

Bringing your app to the foreground when it hasn't been explicitly opened by the user is considered a bad practice and discouraged. In fact, [it won't be allowed in Android Q](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/background-activity-starts), except in a few cases:

> Android Q places restrictions on when apps can start activities. This
>   behavior change helps minimize interruptions for the user and keeps
>   the user more in control of what's shown on their screen. In
>   particular, apps running on Android Q can start activities only when
>   one or more of the following conditions are met:
>
> 1. The app has a visible window, such as an activity in the foreground.
> 2. A different app that's in the foreground sends a PendingIntent belonging to the app. Examples include a Custom Tabs provider sending
>      a menu item pending intent.
> 3. The system sends a PendingIntent that belongs to the app, such as tapping on a notification. Only pending intents where the app is
>      expected to launch a UI are exempt.
> 4. The system sends a broadcast, such as SECRET_CODE_ACTION, to the app. Only specific broadcasts where the app is expected the launch a
>      UI are exempt.

Therefore, I would definitely recommend you to discard the idea.

Comment: Hmm I think that I wasn't clear. I don't want to force my app back to foreground, BUT if the user brings it back to foreground in the situation where Android killed my app task for resource purposes, I want the app to relaunch, instead of go back to where it was left.

Comment: I initially thought/guessed that you didn't really want to bring the app back to the foreground, but then I asked you if you wanted the app to behave like the user clicked on it and you said yes. Thanks for the clarification on that. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do what you are asking for, or whether it is possible. Good luck with it!